# Custom url display same page

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My application creates custom url's  for its users. Eg: `www.example.com/user1`
Till here everything works fine. But the custom pages like `www.example.com/about` or `www.example.com/terms` show the same content as of custom URL's because according to my .htaccess file anything after 'example.com/' will show the content of 'admin.php' file. How can I differentiate the two situations.

Comment: "according to my .htaccess file anything after 'example.com/' will show the content of 'admin.php'". this seems like a really, really poor idea that you need to work around on every single page, perhaps you should consider an alternative .htaccess rule.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `www.example.com/user1` to `www.example.com/users/user1` or you could change `www.example.com/about` to `www.example.com/pages/about`

Comment: If you look at facebook's profile url's . How do they manage?

Answer (score 0):

personally i tend to go with naming the object in the url such that i can create rewriterule based on the type of object, such as:

```
http://www.example.com/users/username
http://www.example.com/pages/about
http://www.example.com/news/xyz
```

If this isnt a valid solution, you will be best served, using a single "portal" index page and resolving the correct route in PHP. So your rewriterule would be like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Then in the index.php you would parse the URL using much more complex logic such as:

```
<?php
$requested_url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$requested_url = array_shift($requested_url); 
$requested_url_parts = explode('/', $requested_url);

if(!empty($requested_url_parts) && empty($requested_url_parts[0]))
     array_shift($requested_url_parts);

if(end($requested_url_parts) == "") 
     array_pop($requested_url_parts);

reset($requested_url_parts);

/* you now have an array of each part of the URL, so now you can load the valid page */
/* So to start maybe do a mysql lookup to see if current($requested_url_parts) is a valid username or not, if it is, load user page, if not, check if its a valid page e.c.t. */

?>
```